# How to get the height when knowing the width of the label in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, text, label, height

Hi everyone i am using java swing now.
I have a problem like this:
I have a pretty long piece of text and put it in a label with the `<html>` tag.

`<html> My text </html>`

If the text is too long, it will break the line according to the width of the label.
How to calculate the number of line breaks? or height needed to display text after line breaks

This is my code

```java
public Test() {
        initComponents();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        add(new JLabel("<html> "
                + "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like)."
                + "</html>"));
    }
```

[image]

How to know the exact height needed to display the text?

Comment: It's hard to calculate the number of line breaks as you'd need information on the font (individual character size), the text size, how the lines are broken (e.g. what happens to long words) etc. - Can't you either make more space available, let the label dynamically resize or put it into a scroll pane?

Comment: The first question is, why is that important?  Why not just `pack` the frame or make use of `JScrollPane`?

Comment: You could also try making use of [`SwingUtilities#layoutCompoundLabel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#layoutCompoundLabel(javax.swing.JComponent,%20java.awt.FontMetrics,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Rectangle,%20java.awt.Rectangle,%20java.awt.Rectangle,%20int)) [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193933/getting-the-bounds-of-the-text-inside-a-jlabel/50194325#50194325) - but again, this is a rather deep dive that you might need to make

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am wanting to create a dialog that displays a message with a custom dialog size according to the message content to display. If using JScrollPanel will not be convenient for users

Comment: A `JScrollPane` would be more convenient then a dialog which takes up the whole or more of the screen, just saying. *"dialog size according to the message content to display"* - I would start with `pack`ing the dialog and seeing where that takes you

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Here's the GUI I created.  Your code wasn't runnable.  When I made it runnable, your HTML didn't specify any line breaks, so there weren't any line breaks.

[image: Example]

Generally, you use a `JTextArea` for really long text.  You specify the number of rows and columns that you want.  By adjusting the rows and columns, you indirectly adjust the size of the component.

I put the `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane` so my sizing of the component is independent of the length of the text.  I sometimes use a `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane` for my instructions dialogs.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LongJLabel implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new LongJLabel());

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Long JLabel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 40);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setText("It is a long established fact that a reader will be "
                + "distracted by the readable content of a page when "
                + "looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem "
                + "Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal "
                + "distribution of letters, as opposed to using "
                + "'Content here, content here', making it look like "
                + "readable English. Many desktop publishing packages "
                + "and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their "
                + "default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' "
                + "will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. "
                + "Various versions have evolved over the years, "
                + "sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose "
                + "(injected humour and the like).");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        textArea.setCaretPosition(0);
        panel.add(scrollPane);

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Or a `JTextPane` or `JEditorPane` for more stylised text (like HTML), but the basic principle is otherwise unchanged 

Answer (score 0):

Getting the exact required height seems to be non-trivial. Though you could use an "educated guessing" method to calculate the required height.

```
String text = "Your text here";
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html> "
    + text
    + "</html>");
//You can get very useful Information via the Font Metrics class
FontMetrics fm = label.getFontMetrics(label.getFont());

//Here you need a reference to your window so you can get the width of it.
//Via the stringWidth function you get the width of the text when written as one line
//Subtracting 40 is to counter the effect, that the text is broken after each line
//The (int) (...) + 1 is just to round up
int lines = (int) (fm.stringWidth(text) / (window.getWidth() - 40f)) + 1;

//last you can set the window height however you like but watch out
//since the window top margin has to be minded
window.setSize(200, lines * fm.getHeight() + 30);
```

Comment: My immediate issue is, HTML text tends to render differently then normal text so simply "assuming" the `FontMetrics` isn't enough

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the code of class `javax.swing.JLabel` and also performed some experiments and discovered that when the text of the `JLabel` starts with `<html>`, a client property – named *html* – is set and the property value has type `javax.swing.text.View`.

Note that if the `JLabel` text does **not** start with `<html>` then there is no *html* [client] property.

`View` has method `getPreferredSpan` which returns the width of the entire text (of the `JLabel`) and the height of a single line (depending on the parameter used when calling the method – see below code).

Assuming the total width you wish to assign is arbitrary (in the code in your question I believe that the width is 200), you can calculate how many lines will be required. From there you can calculate the required height.

I still haven't discovered why the calculated number of lines is 2 smaller than the required number so I added 2 to the calculated value.

Also note that I set the preferred size of the `JLabel`, rather than the *window* (i.e. `JFrame`) and also call method `pack` so that the *window* size will suit the `JLabel` preferred size.

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.text.View;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            String text = "<html>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted " +
                          "by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The " +
                          "point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal " +
                          "distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content " +
                          "here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing " +
                          "packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default " +
                          "model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web " +
                          "sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the " +
                          "years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour " +
                          "and the like).";
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
            View view = (View) label.getClientProperty("html");
            float textWidth = view.getPreferredSpan(View.X_AXIS);
            float charHeight = view.getPreferredSpan(View.Y_AXIS);
            double lines = Math.ceil(textWidth / 200) + 2;
            double height = lines * charHeight;
            label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, (int) Math.ceil(height)));
            frame.add(label);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```